# Display different number of records at each page in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is my code which displays 10 records par page in gridview

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
                count += 1;
}

cnt = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

PagedDataSource pageData = new PagedDataSource();
pageData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
pageData.AllowPaging = true;

if (PgNum < 1)
{
    pageData.PageSize = 10;
}
else
{
    pageData.PageSize = 10;
}

pageData.CurrentPageIndex = PgNum;

int vcnt = cnt / pageData.PageSize;

if (PgNum < 1)
{
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    lnkPrevious.Visible = false;
}
else if (PgNum > 0)
{
    Panel1.Visible = false;
    lnkPrevious.Visible = true;
}

if (PgNum == vcnt)
{
   lnkNext.Visible = false;
}
else if (PgNum < vcnt)
{
   lnkNext.Visible = true;
}

repeatValues.DataSource = pageData;
repeatValues.DataBind();
```

I want to display 10 Records in first page and 20 records from second page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the default pagesize to 10 in design.

```
<asp:GridView ID ="grid" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="DocumentID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="10" AllowPaging ="true" OnPageIndexChanged ="grid_PageIndexChanged"  >
```

And do following in code in grid_PageIndexChanged event.

```
protected void grid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var pagenum = this.grid.PageIndex;

   if (pagenum + 1 > 1)
   {
     this.grid.PageSize = 20;

   }
   else
   {
     this.grid.PageSize = 10;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

if (!IsPostBack)

{

PopulateData();//This is your table data method 

}

}

protected void ChangePage(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)

{

GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

this.PopulateData();

}
```

---

Its another code behind

```
public DataTable SelectTopRows(DataTable dt, int count)
{
DataTable dtnew  = dt.Clone();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    dtnew.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
}
return dtnew ;
```

---

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=244

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display `10 records` in the first page and `20 records` in the later pages in `GridView` then the solution will be:

**In .aspx page**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CompanyID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" >
...

</asp:GridView>
```

**In .aspx.cs page**

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    if(e.NewPageIndex != 0)
        GridView1.PageSize = 20;
    else
        GridView1.PageSize = 10;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I hope it will help.